# Were method cascades ever considered for C#?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, smalltalk, dart

Smalltalk supports a syntax feature called "message cascades". [Cascades are being adopted](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m1-language-changes/#cascades) by the [Dart Programming language](http://www.dartlang.org/).

As far as I know, C# doesn't support this. Were they ever considered during the design of the language? Is it conceivable that they could appear in a future version of the language?

Comment: look at LinQ, is that what u look for?

Comment: Notice also that cascade methods are very useful in Smalltalk because if there is no explicit return in a method, a method answers 'self', therefore, cascading is easier.

Answer (score 16):

Fluent interfaces are easily supported in C# by using `return` `this`.

In Linq, extension methods are used to accomplish the same thing.  Extension methods over `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` are easily chained together.

Cascades, as described by the page at the link you provided, seem to be merely a subtle refinement of an ordinary Fluent Interface where `return` `this` is not required to make it work, as all method calls beginning with `..` refer to the first returned result:

```
query('#my-form').query('button')
    ..classes.add('toggle')
    ..text = 'Click Me!'
    ..labels.add(toggleLabel);
```

Does C# support this?  No, not exactly.  But you can still write the following equivalent code:

```
var result = query('#my-form').query('button')
result.classes.add('toggle')
result.text = 'Click Me!'
result.labels.add(toggleLabel);
```

and it is only slightly more verbose (and arguably easier to read).

As to the question, "Were they ever considered for C#," you would have to ask Anders Hejlsberg or Eric Lippert about that.  My guess is that they view it as syntactic sugar, which in fact it is.

Comment: The point is that you can re-use the methods in other contexts where you might need the return value. This makes sense when getters and setters are in fact the same method (i.e. a setter returns the old value and sets the argument, if given). This of course doesn’t fit idiomatic C# code anyway.